# SoapClient manage error / exception

Tags: php, soap, error-handling, wsdl

I'm using a soap service that is unavailable today. It's returning a 403 Forbidden code, and then I got this message :

```
 Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from...[MY URL]
```

How can I catch this SoapFault ?

Here is my code :

```
$client = new SoapClient($myurl);
```

I also tried to use the 2nd cosntructor argument with `trace` and `exception(s)` (with and without s, saw the two versions on the net. Can't find the doc).

I tried to catch the thrown error using

```
catch (SoapFault $exception) {
    wtf($exception->getMessage());
}
```

or

```
 catch (Exception $e){
    wtf($e->getMessage());
}
```

(As seen in official doc comments)
Nothing works. Still this Fatal Error and SoapFault uncaught.

I also tried @ before new SoapClient,
and catch with and without backslash (because i'm in a namespace).

At this point, I don't know what to do to handle this error properly.

Maybe a chicken sacrifice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved, the right way is in fact

```
['exceptions' => true]
```

And the exception must be caught with

```
catch (\SoapFault $exception) {
    wtf($exception);
}
```

Comment: This allowed me to catch Soap exceptions. catch(SoapFault $e) doesn't work and doesn't produce any error message, but catch(\SoapFault $e) does work. Thanks!